# How to single step thru Catel code while debugging

Tags: catel

I'm using the Catel demo and trying to single step through the Catel code in it. According to [this](https://www.catelproject.com/2014/04/29/stepping-catel-code-debugging/), I should be able to do so, but it doesn't work for me. As instructed, I've selected the option to Enable source server support.

[image: VS options for debugging]

If I try to single step code such as the following, it steps through the constructor for `PersonViewModel`, which is in the demo, but not through the Catel code.

```
var personViewModel = typeFactory.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<PersonViewModel>(person);
```

I updated the Catel.Core and Catel.MVVM to v5.12.4 to the latest version and likewise associated packages. I'm using .NET Framework 4.8.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled *Source Link* support, which is correct. Other things that might cause this not to work are:

1. Make sure just my code is disabled (it's enabled in your settings, Catel code isn't your code for a debugger instance)
2. Make sure that, under the *symbols* tab, you have selected a directory

Comment: I checked both, just my code is enabled and Cache symbols in this directory has a folder. Still no joy. Possibly relevant is that after a huge Windows update and restart, VS told me I needed to have .NET Framework 4.8 installed (never seen this before) & I installed the runtime.

Comment: Just my code should be disabled, I made a mistake in explaining that, but it's fixed now

Comment: That did it. Thanks.